# how to write stream.rdbuff in file

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I tried to write stream.rdbuf() to a file but it doesn't seem to work, just a blank file, I don`t know what to do.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>

char buffer [9999999];

int main()
{
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream stream;
    stream.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(60));
    stream.connect("www.mail.ru","http");
    stream << "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    stream << "Host mail.ru\r\n";
    stream << "User-Agent   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.47 Safari/536.11\r\n";
    stream << "Accept   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n" ;
    stream << "Accept-Encoding  gzip,deflate,sdch\r\n";
    stream << "Accept-Language  en-US,en;q=0.8\r\n";
    stream <<"Accept-Charset    ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3\r\n";
    stream << "Cookie   \r\n\r\n";
    stream.flush();
    using namespace std ;
    cout << stream.rdbuf();
    ofstream f("output.txt" /*| ios::bin*/);
    f << stream.rdbuf();
    f.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking `stream.rdbuf()` twice: once for the standard out `cout` and then for the file.

It is unclear from your explanation whether you see anything outputed on the screen (when you write to `cout`).

1) If yes, you need to write that to the file instead: by the time you read the stream again, it is exhausted and does not contain anything.

Just remove the

```
cout << stream.rdbuf();
```

line.

If you need to see the result on the screen as well, capture it in a `std::stringstream` first, then you can output its content to both the screen and the file (use `seekp` on the `stringstream` to reset it after the first extraction)

2) If you do not see the results on the screen, you most likely have a problem with connecting to the service